# Return multiple images from a custom dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a set of bags of frames obtained from YouTube videos and I would like to return an entire bag when I iterate my dataset. My custom dataset class is the following one:

```
dataset_path = Path('/content/VideoClassificationDataset')

class VideoDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, dictionary, transform = None):
    self.l_dict = list(dictionary.items())
    self.transform = transform
  
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.l_dict)

  def __get_item__(self, index):
    item = self.l_dict[index]

    images_path = item[0]
    images = [Image.open(f'{dataset_path}/{images_path}/{image}') for image in os.listdir(f'{dataset_path}/{images_path}')]
    
    y_labels = torch.tensor(item[1])

    if self.transform:
      for image in images: self.transform(image)
    
    return images, y_labels
```

Moreover I’ve done also

```
def spit_train(train_data, perc_val_size):
  train_size = len(train_data)
  val_size = int((train_size * perc_val_size) // 100)
  train_size -= val_size

  return random_split(train_data, [int(train_size), int(val_size)])

train_data, val_data = spit_train(VideoDataset(train_dict, transform=train_transform()), 20)
test_data = VideoDataset(dictionary=test_dict, transform=test_transform())


BATCH_SIZE = 16
NUM_WORKERS = os.cpu_count()

def generate_dataloaders(train_data, test_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=NUM_WORKERS):

  train_dl = DataLoader(dataset = train_data, 
                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                num_workers = NUM_WORKERS,
                                shuffle = True)

  val_dl = DataLoader(dataset = val_data, 
                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                num_workers = NUM_WORKERS,
                                shuffle = True)

  test_dl = DataLoader(dataset = test_data, 
                              batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                              num_workers = NUM_WORKERS, 
                              shuffle = False) # don't need to shuffle testing data when we are considering time series dataset

  return train_dl, val_dl, test_dl

train_dl, val_dl, test_dl = generate_dataloaders(train_data, test_data)
```

The *train_dict* and *test_dict* are dictionaries that contains the path of each bag of shots as key and the list of labels as value, like so:

```
{'train/iqGq-8vHEJs/bag_of_shots0': [2],
 'train/iqGq-8vHEJs/bag_of_shots1': [2],
 'train/gnw83R8R6jU/bag_of_shots0': [119],
 'train/gnw83R8R6jU/bag_of_shots1': [119],
...
}
```

The point is that when I try to see what the dataloader contains:

```
train_features_batch, train_labels_batch = next(iter(train_dl))
print(train_features_batch.shape, train_labels_batch.shape)

val_features_batch, val_labels_batch = next(iter(val_dl))
print(val_features_batch.shape, val_labels_batch.shape)
```

I get:

```
NotImplementedError: Caught NotImplementedError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 302, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 58, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 58, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py", line 295, in __getitem__
    return self.dataset[self.indices[idx]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py", line 53, in __getitem__
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

I’m not particularly sure If I can return a set of images in my get_item() function at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the function name, instead of `__get_item__`, the name should be `__getitem__`.

Since this is not defined in your custom dataset class, the function from the base class (`torch.utils.data.Dataset`) is used, which doesn't implement this since it needs to be implemented by each dataset that inherits from this class. So you get an `NotImplementedError`.

More documentation on this can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).

Comment: That was an easy one for you, I've checked all except the syntax of the function. I'm fealing a little stupid right now. Anyway thank you!